# Foxit Reader Command Line Arguments (Return Error Codes?)

Tags: error-handling, batch-file, foxit

Using Foxit Reader through batch file to print PDF files via a FOR loop:

```
SET printing=C:\PDF\Printing
SET fox=C:\Program Files\Foxit Software\Foxit Reader\Foxit Reader.exe
FOR %%F IN (%printing%\*.*) DO "%fox%" -p "%%~fF"
```

I would like to create an IF statement that calls the error code of the command and allows me to do something with it.  Does anyone know how the error codes are stored (or if FOXIT returns error codes for the command line print command?)

I.E.

```
FOR %%F IN (%printing%\*.*) DO (
IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" (
"%fox%" -p "%%~fF"
) ELSE (
ECHO %%~nxF FAILED TO PRINT>>Errorlog.txt
)
)
```

Comment: Received communication from Foxit's support department and they state that Foxit does not store errorlevels if an error occurs, only an event is called. So scratch that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround:

```
CSCRIPT C:\WINDOWS\system32\PRNJOBS.VBS -l
```

Used with the 'l' switch, it will list all printjobs currently being processed by the localhost.  I can at least pipe a find command to locate the current printjob in the queue and if it doesn't exist, I know that it failed to print and then I can perform errorhandling on the file.