# Batch Script - Verify a printed file went to the print queue

Tags: batch-file, filenames, printqueue

Windows XP w/Network Printers (\server\printer1)

Making a batch script for printing PDF files via FoxitReader and Foxit does not store errorlevels, so I'm trying to find a way for the script to verify that the file being processed made it to the print queue then I can use that verification to handle errors.  I've tried

```
net print \\server\printer
```

but it gives no file names.

So is there a way to verify a file went to the print queue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEE:

> [Foxit Reader Command Line Arguments (Return Error Codes?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256906/foxit-reader-command-line-arguments-return-error-codes)